# GPU memory doesn't get freed up after evaluating data on PyTorch model in parallel process

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, python-multiprocessing

For my optimization algorithm, I need to evaluate a few hundred images every iteration. To speed up the process, I wanted to take full advantage of my 3 GPUs.

My process:

- Load an instance of my deep learning model on each one of my GPUs
- Then split the workload into as many parts as I have GPUs
- pair each workload in a tuple with the instance of the GPU loaded model it should be processed on
- run starmap(_runDataThroughModel, sub_workload) to process all sub_workload in parallel

Now there is no problem with doing this once and ending the problem, however, when I do this repeatedly the GPU memory starts to fill up with each iteration until I get a "RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory"

**My Question:**

- What is the correct way of going about this?
- Why is the GPU memory
  not freed? Since I pre-instantiate the GPU model outside the
  "starmap" command and always pass the same instances, why would there
  be a buildup?

**Update**
I re-wrote the code taking into account the issue presented in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561124/python-multithreading-in-infinite-loop). Instantiating Pool() outside of any loop in the program didn't solve the GPU memory overflow, however, it stopped the CPU memory from building up over time.

```
'''
Test GPU Memory Leak
Description: Tests how the memory doesn't get freed up when running multiprocessing with PyTorch Model forward pass
'''
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import importlib
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io, transform
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.io._plugins.pil_plugin import *
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn

# Convolutional neural network (twohttps://duckduckgo.com/?q=install+gmsh+conda&t=canonical convolutional layers)
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10, num_img_layers = 1, img_res = 128):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            #torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1,  
            # padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros')
            nn.Conv2d(num_img_layers, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU())
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*int(img_res/2)*int(img_res/2), 32*32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32*32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        #print(x.shape)
        out = self.layer1(x)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

class NNEvaluator:
    def __init__(self, model_dict, GPU, img_res = 128, num_img_layers = 1, num_classes = None):
        # Load the model checkpoint
        gpu_id = 'cuda:' + str(GPU)
        self.device = torch.device(gpu_id if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.model_state_dict = model_dict['model_state_dict']
        self.model = ConvNet(num_classes = num_classes, num_img_layers = num_img_layers, img_res = img_res).to(self.device)
        self.model.to(self.device)
        self.model.load_state_dict(self.model_state_dict)

        self.epsilon = torch.tensor(1e-12, dtype = torch.float)
    def evaluate(self, img):
        self.model.eval() 
        with torch.no_grad():
            img = img.to(self.device)
            out = self.model(img)
            out = out.to('cpu')
        return out
def loadImage(filename):
    im = Image.open("test.jpg")
    im = io._plugins.pil_plugin.pil_to_ndarray(im)
    im = rgb2gray(im)
    image = im.transpose((0, 1))
    im = torch.from_numpy(image).float()
    im = torch.unsqueeze(im,0)
    im = torch.unsqueeze(im,1)
    return im

def _worker(workload, evaluator):
    results = []
    for img in workload:
        results.append(evaluator.evaluate(img))
def main():
    # load a model for each GPU
    model_dict = torch.load('model_dict.ckpt')
    GPUs = [0,1,2] # available GPUs in the system
    evaluators = []
    for gpu_id in GPUs:
        evaluators.append(NNEvaluator(model_dict, gpu_id, num_classes=3))    
    # instantiate multiprocessing pool
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    mypool = mp.Pool()

    # evaluate all datapoints 20 times
    im = loadImage('test.jpg')
    total_nr_iterations = 20
    for i in range(total_nr_iterations):
        # run a subset of the workload on each GPU in a separate process
        nr_datapoints = 99
        dp_per_evaluator = int(nr_datapoints/len(evaluators))
        workload = [im for i in range(dp_per_evaluator)]
        jobslist = [(workload, evaluator) for evaluator in evaluators]
        mypool.starmap(_worker, jobslist)
        print("Finished iteration {}".format(i))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output when running the code:

```
Finished iteration 0
Finished iteration 1
Finished iteration 2
Process SpawnPoolWorker-10:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 119, in rebuild_cuda_tensor
    event_sync_required)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 119, in rebuild_cuda_tensor
    event_sync_required)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
Process SpawnPoolWorker-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/ron/miniconda3/envs/PyTorchNN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 119, in rebuild_cuda_tensor
    event_sync_required)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561124/python-multithreading-in-infinite-loop) where the memory leakage occurs due to the instantiation of the Pool() in the loop, rather than outside.

The above problem also instantiates the Pool() inside the function without using the `with` notation which would ensure that all started processes return

E.g. bad way:

```
def evaluation(workload):
    jobslist = [job for job in workload]
    with Pool() as mypool:
        mypool.starmap(_workerfunction, jobslist)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pseudo data
    workload = [[(100,200) for i in range(1000)] for i in range(50)]
    for i in range(100):
        evaluation(workload)
```

The proper way of doing this would be to instantiate the pool outside the loop, and pass a reference to the pool into the function for processing i.e.:

```
def evaluation(workload, mypool):
    jobslist = [job for job in workload]
    mypool.starmap(_workerfunction, jobslist)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pseudo data
    with Pool() as mypool:
        workload = [[(100,200) for i in range(1000)] for i in range(50)]
        for i in range(100):
            evaluation(workload, mypool)
```

I suspect that the GPU memory gets leaked due to left over references in parallel processes that have not been cleaned up yet.